# Count number of values followed by another value in r

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(Year = c("May","June","July"), 
                 D1 = c(0,0,0), 
                 D2 = c(0,0,0), 
                 D3 = c(0,0,0), 
                 D4 = c(0,0,1), 
                 D5 = c(0,1,1),
                 D6 = c(0,1,1),
                 D7 = c(0,0,0),
                 D8 = c(0,0,0),
                 D9 = c(0,0,0),
                 D10 = c(0,0,0),
                 D11 = c(0,0,0),
                 D12 = c(0,0,0),
                 D13 = c(0,0,0), 
                 D14 = c(1,1,0), 
                 D15 = c(1,0,0),
                 D16 = c(0,1,0),
                 D17 = c(1,1,1),
                 D18 = c(0,0,0),
                 D19 = c(0,0,0),
                 D20 = c(0,0,0),
                 D21 = c(0,1,0),
                 D22 = c(0,0,0),
                 D23 = c(0,1,0), 
                 D24 = c(0,0,0), 
                 D25 = c(0,0,0),
                 D26 = c(1,0,0),
                 D27 = c(0,0,0),
                 D28 = c(1,0,1),
                 D29 = c(1,0,0),
                 D30 = c(1,1,0),
                 D31 = c(0,1,1)
                 )
```

I have a data frame (subset above) of months and days.  I am trying to count the number of days a 1 is followed by a 0, 0 is followed by a 1, etc.  For example, May would have 2 ones followed by zeros and two zeros followed by 1s. I am thinking a for loop would be the best way to go about this but am having trouble since the comparisons are in rows.

Comment: Can you check the updated solution.  I think the earlier solution with `str_extract` or `str_count` was based on the logic that once an element in position is counted/extracted, it is not used again. With rolling `paste` with `2` elements at a time, it solves that issue.  Or you could use `lag` as well to `paste` and then count with `table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the updated data, we may need rolling `paste`

```
library(zoo)
out <- table(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) rollapply(x, 2, paste, collapse="")))
out
#   00 01 10 11 
#   56 14 12  8 

sum(out)
#[1] 90
```

Or can be be made a bit more compact without the anonymous function call

```
table(apply(df[-1], 1, rollapply, width = 2, paste, collapse=""))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(runner)
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
    rowwise %>%
    summarise(out = list(table(runner(c_across(starts_with('D')),
          f = function(x) paste(x, collapse=""), k = 2))), .groups = 'drop') %>%
    unnest_wider(c(out))  %>%
    adorn_totals() 
#     0 00 01 10 11
#     1 19  4  4  3
#     1 16  6  5  3
#     1 21  4  3  2
# Total 56 14 12  8
```

Comment: It is not working on my larger data frame with all 12 months and 28 days each. Can you please explain what your code is doing so i can see where it is off?

Comment: what does the .x refer to?

Comment: @user10256905 It is a lambda function value i..e `~` equal to `function(x)`. with `map`, it would be `.x`

Comment: Month 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31  
1 May 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  
2 June 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  
3 July 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1 This is the full first three months, in which the code does not work and im confused why

Comment: @user10256905 sorry, not following your data from the comments.

Comment: i updated the question with a full three rows of data.  It should give 90 values total and its only giving 63

Comment: @user10256905 can you check my updated post

Comment: thank you so much, i tried the one with the zoo package and it works wonderfully!

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `gregexpr`

```
v <- do.call(paste0, df[-1])
rev(
  stack(
    sapply(
      c("00", "01", "10", "11"),
      function(x) sum(lengths(regmatches(v, gregexpr(x, v)))),
      USE.NAMES = TRUE
    )
  )
)
```

gives

```
  ind values
1  00      1
2  01      5
3  10      4
4  11      1
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already recognized the trouble is in the row comparison... then we can reshape the data from wide format to long format.

`Warning: In your data, due to the wide format June have 31 days as May/July.`

```
reshape_df <- df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = D1:D31, names_to = "date", values_to = "value") %>%
  mutate(index = if_else(value != lag(value), 1, 0)) %>%
  replace_na(list(index = 0)) %>%
  mutate(index_group = cumsum(index))

reshape_df %>%
  group_by(index_group) %>%
  summarize(first_month = first(Year),
            first_date = first(date),
            first_value = first(value),
            length = n())
```

Result for this data.

```
   index_group first_month first_date first_value length pattern
         <dbl> <chr>       <chr>            <dbl>  <int> <chr>  
 1           0 May         D1                   0     13 0 -> 1 
 2           1 May         D14                  1      2 1 -> 0 
 3           2 May         D16                  0      1 0 -> 1 
 4           3 May         D17                  1      1 1 -> 0 
 5           4 May         D18                  0      8 0 -> 1 
 6           5 May         D26                  1      1 1 -> 0 
 7           6 May         D27                  0      1 0 -> 1 
 8           7 May         D28                  1      3 1 -> 0 
 9           8 May         D31                  0      5 0 -> 1 
10           9 June        D5                   1      2 1 -> 0 
# … with 18 more rows
```